# How to find affine transformation of a unit square

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

How to find affine transformation of a unit  square centered at origin , which is translated half the length of side along its diagonal into a square with length of sides as half.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What have you tried? I would do it step-by-step, starting first with the stretching of the dimensions, and then the translation.